# Short script that displays the code itself?

Tags: perl

Wondering if it's possible to write a short script that prints the code itself out in the end with the lines counted. Even something simple like a few lines of

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

print "Hello there";
print "This got me scratching my head";
```

And the output would be this code itself with the lines counted.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Are you asking about a quine, or about printing the contents of the file followed by a line count?

Comment: hey there, Im not sure what the quine is, idk if I explained it correctly, basically that code itself would be the desireable output, like it would just print itself with the amount of code lines counted.

Comment: After reading up on it yes, its supposed to be the quine I think.

Comment: In a typical quine code challenge, it is prohibited to use the language's input features to, say, load the source code into a variable and then output that variable. That restriction does not seem to apply here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
use warnings;
use strict;

print "Hello there";
print "This got me scratching my head";

open (my $f, '<', $0);
while (<$f>){print};
print "read $. lines\n";
```

The variable `$0` or `$PROGRAM_NAME` holds the name of your program.

Or (with linecount on each line)

```
use warnings;
use strict;

print "Hello there";
print "This got me scratching my head\n";

open (my $f, '<', $0);
while (<$f>){printf "%03d %s",$., $_};
print "read $. lines\n";
```

The variable `$.` or `$INPUT_LINE_NUMBER` contains the current line number for the last filehandle accessed.

See [perlvar](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar)

Also see [mobs answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66053716/10667839) for a way to read the file using `DATA`

Answer (score 2):

The name of the script being executed is in the variable `$0`, so the straightforward way to accomplish this is

```
...
open(my $ZERO,"<",$0);
my @lines = <$ZERO>;
close $ZERO;
print @lines, "count = ", 0+@lines, "\n";
...
```

When `$0` is unavailable because you have changed directories or overwritten it, another option is to use the special `DATA` handle which is opened on a file that contains the special `__END__` or `__DATA__` tokens.

```
...
seek DATA, 0, 0;   # seek to begin of file, not begin of __DATA__ section
my @lines = <DATA>;
print @lines, "count = ",0+@lines,"\n";
...
__DATA__
...
```